Vue 3 Suspense Fallback Displays Multiple Times on Fast Page Navigation
I’m working on a Vue 3 application that uses RouterView, Transition, and Suspense for page transitions and loading states. The issue occurs when I navigate between pages quickly. During fast navigation, the fallback component for <Suspense> (<PageLoading/>) displays multiple times, leading to multiple loading components appearing on the screen.
Here's the relevant code for the layout and page transitions:
<template>
  <RouterView v-slot="{ Component, route }">
    <template v-if="Component">
      <Transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
        <Suspense timeout="100">
          <Component :is="`${route.meta?.layout || 'dashboard'}Layout`">
            <Transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
              <Suspense timeout="100">
                <Component :is="Component"/>
                <template #fallback>
                  <PageLoading/>
                </template>
              </Suspense>
            </Transition>
          </Component>
          <template #fallback>
            <LayoutLoading/>
          </template>
        </Suspense>
      </Transition>
    </template>
  </RouterView>
</template>

Question:
How can I ensure that  (the fallback for Suspense) only displays once during fast page navigation, and prevent multiple fallback components from stacking?
Any advice or suggestions to manage this better with Vue 3 transitions and Suspense would be greatly appreciated!
Environment:
Vue 3
Vue Router 4
Using Suspense for handling async components
Expected Behavior:
When navigating between pages, I expect the fallback component () to display only once during the transition.
Actual Behavior:
If I navigate between different pages rapidly, the  component (inner Suspense fallback) displays multiple times, causing several loading components to show on the screen simultaneously.
What I’ve Tried:

I’ve attempted using Transition with mode="out-in" to ensure smooth page transitions.
I’ve used Suspense to handle loading states with a timeout of 100ms.
I’ve checked if wrapping the transitions differently would resolve it, but the issue persists during fast navigation.

